# How to upgrade lastest version of teamviewer on ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, teamviewer

I'm using Teamviewer version 10. I want to upgrade to the latest version (11 at this time). How to implement on terminal?

Comment: How did you install the old TeamViewer version 10?

Comment: @ByteCommander I download this version on offical website and command `sudo apt-get install **package**`. I don't remember that because of long time ago.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Download it from their official website :

```
# 64 bits version
wget https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/teamviewer_amd64.deb 

# or the 32 bits version 
wget http://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_i386.deb

# or the Raspberry Pi version
wget https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/teamviewer-host_armhf.deb
```

Install it :

```
sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_*.deb
```

Install missing dependencies :

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: I want to **update** this software

Comment: @Lợi - well you can't.

Comment: For 64 Bit Systems use  
wget https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/teamviewer_amd64.deb

Comment: Does this show a UI or can this be done completely from the terminal?

Answer (score 10):

As you have version 10 or version 12 or current version. First you need to uninstall that version 10 or current installed version and install new version 11 or version 13.

1. Uninstall version 10 or current version of your computer.

> $ sudo apt-get remove teamv*
>
> $ sudo apt-get purge teamviewer

2. After uninstallation of previous version, install new version using following steps.
3. Download latest version from official teamviewer website https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/.
4. Go to the downloaded directory and run following command.

> $ sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_****.deb
>
> $ sudo apt-get -f install

This process will help you little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Download the version you want to update to, from teamviewer's official site.  Then use the above sudo commands to install the new version.
This will overwrite the older version, but will have some issues with overwriting log folders. So, better option is to remove the older version and install a new one.

Comment: Please don't create incomplete answers that rely on other answers. If you want to improve a different answer suggest a change with the "edit" link below it. If you want to change it drastically, write a stand-alone answer and cite the relevant parts of the other answer *inline*.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the older version & Go to [Official TeamViewer Website](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/windows/) & download the Debian Package of the teamviewer version, you want to install.

Then open terminal in the directory in which your package is downloaded.

```
sudo dpkg -i package_name
```

package_name is the name of the package you installed.

For installing the missing dependencies

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```